# how to pass extra value in a html select which we want to use onChange function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
<select className="form-select" onChange={(e)=>changeCountry(e)}>
            <option selected>Country</option>
            {Country.getAllCountries().map((item,index)=>(
              <option value={item.name.toUpperCase()} code={item.isoCode} key={index}>{item.name}</option>
            ))}
          </select>
```

In this select input code i want to save the countries in normal words but i still need the  isoCode because i need to fetch the states of that country

so when i am doing this by changeCountry function

```
const changeCountry = (e)=>{
    setCountry(e.target.value)
    console.log(e.target.code)
    console.log("The state of the country",State.getStatesOfCountry(e.target.code))
    setAllStateType(State.getStatesOfCountry(e.target.code))
    
  }
```

Here why i am getting the code is undefined if i am getting it how can i pass the iso code to  get the states of that country

how i solve this question by passing all the element in the value by Adding + ve sign and then split back

Comment: Why don't you put value = item.isoCode and then get name from .isoCode aslo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it in your script with:

```
.getAttribute('code')
```

but first you need to determine which option is currently selected, so you should modify your function like so:

```
const changeCountry = (e)=>{
    let sel = e.target;
    let code = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].getAttribute('code')
    //do whatever
    
}
```

Check this similar question:
[Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)